# Custom button programmatically android

Tags: java, android, button

I'm creating a list of buttons in Android with the same icon for each of them and then set the text programmatically. So my list has: 
ImageView (always the same) + Text (label for the icon which I set programmatically).

How can I create a something like the icon below but where I can change text dinamically?

Thank you!

[image: button]

Comment: There are many ways to do this. I'd go for a drawable (used as the border of a TextView) and the arrow... just an Unicode character (`\u2bc8`). Note: the darawable might be a StateList, so using different colors for different states of the "Button".

Comment: looks like there is some confusion about what programmatically means. if you find a good solution, please post it.

Comment: I have not found the solution yet.

Answer (score 2):

You can use android:drawableLeft attribute in the TextView. Here's the sample:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    />
```

And the result

[image]

Comment: yes, I've tried something like this but I want also a border all around the textview (like a button).

Comment: moreover if I use the xml for this, I can't create the complete button or something else list dinamically. They are always there at least first time.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you using the following

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_text"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/button_icon"
    ... />
```

If you are looking for more customized button, then probably you should learn more about Custom Views:

https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your question is that you want to change/set the text of the button programmatically.

for this use the following code in onCreate event:

```
Button mybutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.your_button_name);
mybutton.setText("Your Text Here");
```